# Trigger an action when electron app get focus

Tags: vue.js, electron

How can I call an action from my vue store when my electron app comes into focus...?

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow()
win.on('focus', () => {
   //dispatch action call loadSettings()
})
```

Comment: What's wrong with above piece of code?

Comment: I can't import my store into the electron.config.js file.

Comment: Then you can import `BrowserWindow` where you can import `store`.